# Refused connection to RabbitMQ when using docker link

Tags: asp.net-core, rabbitmq, docker-compose, microservices

I have a microservices application which has two services and a rabbit mq used as a message queue for communication between them. Now, I want to deploy them on docker. I have the following code in the `docker-compose.yml` file:

version: "3"
services:

```
  rabbitmq:
    build: ./Rabbit
    hostname: "rabbitmq"
    container_name: "rabbitmq"
    environment:
      RABBITMQ_ERLANG_COOKIE: "cookie"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: "user"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: "pass"
      RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_VHOST: "/"
    ports:
      - "15672:15672"
      - "5672:5672"
    # labels:
    #   NAME: "rabbit1"
    volumes:
    - "/opt/rabbitmq:/var/lib/rabbitmq"

  service1:
    build: ./service1
    deploy:
      replicas: 5
      restart_policy:
        condition: on-failure
      resources:
        limits:
          cpus: "0.1"
          memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "8181:80"
    depends_on:
      - rabbitmq
    links:
     - rabbitmq
    networks:
      - webnet
```

So, here I build the RabbitMQ image in a container and then link this container to the container of `service1`. Since `service1` one is an ASP.NET Core Web API, I use the following setup to connect to the message queue:

```
//Establish the connection
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory
            {
                HostName = "rabbitmq",
                Port = 5672,
                UserName = "user",
                Password = "pass",
                VirtualHost = "/",
                AutomaticRecoveryEnabled = true,
                NetworkRecoveryInterval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
            };
```

But when I try to run `docker-compose up`, I receive the following error message:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the
>   specified endpoints were reachable --->
>   RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed
>   ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException:
>   No such device or address

Maybe I have a mistake in the `HostName` but I am not sure how to correct it.

Comment: They are not on the same network, put `networks: - webnet` to `rabbitmq` service, or create another network just for both of them

Comment: I tried this, it it is still not working, but the exception is the following ```Unhandled Exception: RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: None of the specified endpoints were reachable ---> RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.ConnectFailureException: Connection failed ---> System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException: Connection refused 172.21.0.3:5672```

Comment: We are getting somewhere, at least the hostname is now resolved.

Comment: restart docker and try again

Comment: Well, seems the order of execution is the problem. I see this article https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/ as a possible solution.

Comment: Yes, it could be; anyway, even if the services are started correctly, the time needed to become available changes the effective order; so, you need to implement some `waiting-until-fully-available` mechanism

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems that need to be fixed:

1. the two services do not belong to the same network so you need to add the `rabbitmq` service to the `webnet` network or create a new network for the two services
2. `rabbitmq` may take some time to become fully available (i.e. to listen to the `5672` port) so you need to make the `service1` service to wait for the `rabbitmq` service; see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31746182/docker-compose-wait-for-container-x-before-starting-y) about this issue.