# Docker - RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'

Tags: docker, .net-core, rabbitmq, rabbitmq-exchange

I have set up RabbitMQ server on my dev machine using [this](https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq) docker image.

I have used below command to setup my container

`docker run -d  --name my-rabbit -p 5672:15672 rabbitmq:3-management`

Below is docker ps command output

`CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                   COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS    PORTS                                                                    NAMES
a40704b7f3a4        rabbitmq:3-management   "docker-entrypoint.s…"   13 minutes ago      Up 12 minutes       4369/tcp, 5671-5672/tcp, 15671/tcp, 25672/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5672->15672/tcp   my-rabbit`

Management console is accessible at http://localhost:5672 and I can login using default username and password ( guest/guest )

Below is my .Net Core code

```
public RabbitMQMnager()
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            factory.Port = 5672;
            Uri uri = new Uri("amqp://guest:guest@localhost:5672/");

            var connection = factory.CreateConnection();

            //Below are values of different connection string parameters
            factory.HostName = "localhost";
            factory.UserName = "guest";
            factory.Password = "guest";
            factory.VirtualHost = "/";
            factory.Port = 5672;

            var channel = connection.CreateModel(); //<- Exception here
        }
```

Upon executing above code, I am getting below exception.

```
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.BrokerUnreachableException: 'None of the specified endpoints were reachable'
```

Stack Trace

`This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
    RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.StartAndTune()
    RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.Open(bool)
    RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.Connection.Connection(RabbitMQ.Client.IConnectionFactory, bool, 
    RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.IFrameHandler, string)
    RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.IFrameHandler)
    RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.AutorecoveringConnection.Init(RabbitMQ.Client.IEndpointResolver)
    RabbitMQ.Client.ConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(RabbitMQ.Client.IEndpointResolver, string)`

I found similar questions but solution mentioned there is not enough for me.  It looks like it has something to do with docker and the network created by docker.

[Refused connection to RabbitMQ when using docker link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44802594/refused-connection-to-rabbitmq-when-using-docker-link)

Other details

- .Net Core 3.1 app
- RabbitMQ.Client -> 5.1.2

  **UPDATE 1**

As per @ThisIsNoZaku answer exposing additional port solved my issue.

```
docker run -d --hostname my-rabbit --name my-rabbit -p 15672:15672 -p  5672:5672 rabbitmq:3-management
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The ports to connect to the RabbitMQ instance with an AMQP client and to connect to the management console UI (`15762` in the container, which you've mapped to `5762` on the host) are different. When the application tries to point an AMQP client at the management port, it fails [because it's not supported](https://www.rabbitmq.com/management.html#usage-ui):

> The management UI can be accessed using a Web browser
>
> ...
>
> Note that the UI and HTTP API port — typically 15672 — does not support AMQP 0-9-1, AMQP 1.0, STOMP or MQTT connections. Separate ports should be used by those clients.

Your RabbitMQ instance should expose, and your client connect, to the [correct ports for AMQP](https://www.rabbitmq.com/networking.html#ports):

> 5672, 5671: used by AMQP 0-9-1 and 1.0 clients without and with TLS

Comment: Thanks @ThisIsNoZaku , I have updated my question with your answer.